# Deploying MEAN stack on server

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I want to deploy my application developed in MEAN stack on the server. My server is on the intranet so i cannot install node modules from there. What i wanted to ask is what is the correct way to it. 
I have installed node v-8.9.1 and nginx on my server. I just zip my whole project and unzip it on my server and run `nohup npm start &`. 
Is this the right way to do it or are there any build tools wherein i can just create a war file and deploy it on my server.

Comment: One option is to use ubuntu snappy and compile the app into a snap. You can also `npm install` on the same architecture you are using and simply copy the `node_modules` (or the entire project) folder over (assuming you're not using any global packages)  You can also use Bitnami, or Docker.

Comment: @cody Thanks for the reply. I would also like to add that i use windows environment as my development environment and my production is Linux

Comment: https://github.com/nexe/nexe this seems pretty popular

Comment: @CodyG.: i haven't tried this yet but i was just looking at their github page and this seems to be software which creates a container for a nodejs application.